# Removing quotes in openjpa generated sql for sybase

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, sybase, openjpa

I need to be able to refer to a table on a different schema, using OpenJPA to access a Sybase db.

So, for example, I need to select as follows:

```sql
SELECT name FROM SHARE.dbo.PROVINCE;
```

However, the generated SQL is:

```sql
SELECT name FROM "SHARE.dbo".PROVINCE;
```

which Sybase rejects. Without the quotes it works fine.

I'm using the following annotations on the class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PROVINCE", schema="SHARE.dbo")
```

using `schema="SHARE"` doesn't work, although it generates the sql without any quotes. (Sybase requires schema.owner.table, so `SCHEMA.PROVINCES` is an unknown object)

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the schema to the table name: `@Table(name="SHARE.dbo.PROVINCE")`

Comment: For some reason it cuts off the schema part. Same happens when I do @Table(name="dbo.PROVINCE", schema="SHARE") - the schema part, eg SHARE, seems to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but you could try to disable delimited identifier support?

```
openjpa.DBDictionary=sybase(SupportsDelimitedIdentifiers=false)
```

Comment: It was a long shot, but worth taking. No dice, but thanks. Time to convince dba's to give me better access, I guess :)